# Combinations Problem or Permutations

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

In a competition the members of a committee were given the list of the 6 most popular books. How many possible ways can the committee choose two of the six books to be awarded the 1st and 2nd best book prize money respectively?

I found through combinations that the possible ways of choosing 2 of 6 books, are 15. Am I right or it is permutations? And then, how I continue?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You still have to choose which prize each of the selected books receives.  Can you finish?

Comment: Book-A getting 1st prize, Book-B getting 2nd prize should be considered distinct from Book-B getting 1st prize, Book-A getting 2nd prize.

Comment: Does the order matter?

Answer (score 0):

No,C(6,2) = 15 wouldn’t be the answer,
consider a simpler question where the list would consist of 2 most popular books.(B1 and B2 respectively)
Now,(B1,B2) and (B2,B1) would be the 2 ways for this to happen.(C(2,2)=1)
now consider 3 books,B1,B2,B3.
(B1,B2),(B1,B3),(B2,B3),
(B2,B1),(B2,B3),(B3,B1)
So 6 = 2.C(3,2) ways for this to happen.
Similarly there would 2.C(5,2) possible ways in the original problem